# aframe glTF cube-env-map

Tags: aframe, gltf

I'm unable to see any reflexion on my gtLF model using "cube-env-map".
I'd like to get something like this :
[helmet from threejs.org examples](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf)
I don't know if this is because of the .jpg files I use, or html or linked javascript scripts, or... anything else?
Here's my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script><!-- Master file for aframe (== a-scene) -->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script><!-- webcam/mobilecam --> 
    <script src="https://mkwy.fr/js/play-all-model-animations.js"></script><!-- animation -->
    <script src="https://mkwy.fr/js/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script><!-- orbit cam around target -->
    <script src="https://mkwy.fr/js/aframe-extras.js"></script><!-- cub-env-map -->
  </head>
  <body>
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded>
     <a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="toy" src="https://mkwy.fr/assets/toyDrummerSolo.glb"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>
     <a-entity 
        gltf-model="#toy"
        cube-env-map="path: https://mkwy.fr/assets/cube-env/; extension: jpg; reflectivity: 0.9;" 
        play-all-model-animations >
     </a-entity>
      <a-entity camera look-controls  orbit-controls="target: 0 1 0; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 60; initialPosition: 0 5 5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Huge +1 for this.  That helmet demo looks as shiny as it does because of the use of something called an HDRI, a "High Dynamic Range Image" used as both the lighting environment and reflection environment.  I don't know if a-frame supports setting an HDRI, but it's needed for models like this.

Comment: any console logs?

Comment: console says : three.js:18036 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter.

Comment: I've tried reproducing the issue. Other than an old `a-frame` (0.8.0 vs 1.0.4), I've noticed that Your model could use some `roughness/metalness` tweaking - as I've described in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Assuming there are no console errors suggesting incorrect cubemap paths, or wrong extensions)*

If your model looks like this:
[image]

And you want it to be more like this:
[image]

Then the answer lies in two factors - [metalness, and roughness](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/material.html#environment-maps).

- [roughness](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.roughness) determines whether the material is like a mirror (0), or completely diffuses the reflection (1).
- [metalness](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.metalness) determines whether the material is metallic (1), or not (0).

You can deal with this in at least two ways:

- Modify the materials in a modelling software like blender, or maya.
- Modify the properties within an a-frame custom component.

A component would have to wait until the model is loaded, and change all (or some selected) model nodes. Like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    // wait until the model is loaded
    this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
      // grab the mesh
      let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
      mesh.traverse(node => {
        // ignore nodes without materials
        if (!node.material) return;
        // assign the values.
        node.material.metalness = 1;
        node.material.roughness = 0;
      })
    })
  }
})
```

You can check it out in [this](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/env_cubemap_component_wrong_model.html) example.

---

The helmet is working with both [jpg](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/env_cubemap_component_jpg.html) and [png](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/env_cubemap_component_png.html) maps. As for arjs, if your model will be glitchy, and you'll experience [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), just set the `logarithmicDepthBuffer` in the `renderer`:

```
<a-scene renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true" embedded arjs>
```

Example [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/env_cubemap_component_arjs.html)
.Seems to be working as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I changed the settings in Blender, adding metalness, and now it works like a charm. It was confusing because in Blender you don't need to set metalness to get reflection (i.e. : a plastic bottle may have reflections). I have to play with these parameters. Many thanks!